# How to test a contract that implements EIP712 signatures?

Tags: foundry, eip712

While testing some functions that depend on EIP 712 signatures, in foundry.

Do I need to create my own helper contract or helper function to generate digest etc as mentioned in this doc - https://book.getfoundry.sh/tutorials/testing-eip712

Or is there any way in Foundry that all this can be done with cheatcodes??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been working with the same thing and couldn't find more cheatcodes for this.

But it would be easy to work with it, if you don't wanna create another contract, then just copy the function logic in your test contract. Like I have included the logic directly into my test function.

[image]

But obviously, a helper contract would be more cleaner.